# Agregar cupones de descuento en Wordpress y mostrarlos en la seccion My Account

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

me gustaría mostrar los cupones que genero con Worpdress en la seccion de Mi Cuenta de Woocomerce.
He probado instalando el plugin gratuito "Smart Coupons for WooCommerce" pero no visualiza los cupones, solo queda la pantalla en blanco y un titulo que dice "Available coupons".
Alguien me podria ayudar a resolver este problema? No importa si es con este plugin, o con otro. O simplemente con codigo PHP, solo quiero mostrar los cupones que genero en la seccion de "Mi Cuenta".
Gracias
[image: Asi es como se ve la parte de los cupones en la seccion de "mi cuenta"]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo usando `get_posts`, prueba con lo siguiente:

```
function coupon_list() {
    $coupon_posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'order'            => 'asc',
        'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
    ) );

    $coupon_codes = [];

    foreach( $coupon_posts as $coupon_post) {
        echo $coupon_codes[] = $coupon_post->post_name;
    }

    return implode(', ', $coupon_codes) ;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'coupon_list' );
```

Esto creara una lista con los cupones disponibles, para ponerlo en el dashboard agrega la linea `add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'coupon_list' );` lo importante es esta linea `woocommerce_account_dashboard` que agrega la lista en el area de dashboard de la cuenta del usuario, a esto se le llama hook, puedes consultar la guia de hooks de woocommerce [aqui](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-account-pages/).

Fuentes: [Creating a List of Available WooCommerce Coupon Codes and Display anywhere Using Shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230388/creating-a-list-of-available-woocommerce-coupon-codes-and-display-anywhere-using)

Comment: Hola, he probado el codigo y no funciona, no aparece nada. Tengo el cupon creado

Comment: Puedes hacer un var_dump de $coupon_codes para verificar que información te retorna

Comment: ya esta solucionado, tenia que agregar el email del usuario en la configuracion del plugin, te agradezco por la ayuda :)